# Is this sentence correct? Is it correct to say 'is young women' instead of 'are young women'?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

> The new contract doesn't allow for extended maternity leave; therein lies the problem for the union, 60% of whose membership **is young women**.

Is this sentence correct? Is it correct to say 'is young women' instead of 'are young women'?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395445/why-is-a-singular-verb-is-used-after-one-third-of-the-population-while-a-plu?noredirect=1&lq=1 - does this (and the linked question that this one is a duplicate of) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subject is 60% percent. We need to use a singular verb to mean the subject is regarded as a single unit.